# ALL employees under a director or above using Active Directory and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm attempting to create a cascading drop down in which the first populates a list of Director level employees (directors have multiple managers and the managers have multiple employees) which would then populate the second dropdown through ajax. I'm trying to put together the logic that given a displayname will grab all direct reports and the direct reports of the direct reports. With the logic I've put together it will print everyone im looking for but only returns the reports to the original Director. I'm struggling to put everything together. The code isnt at all pretty and if there's an easier way to do this I'm open for suggestions.

There are three methods in which I'm attempting to populate the `directReports` list in the `DirectReports` method with all employees

```
public List<string> DirectReports(string name)
        {
            List<string> directReports = new List<string>();
            var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "somedomain");
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domain);
            user.DisplayName = name;
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
            ps.QueryFilter = user;
            DirectorySearcher ds = ps.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayName=" + name + "))";
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("DirectReports");
            SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
            foreach(SearchResult result in results)
            {
                if (hasDirectReports(result))
                {
                    //directReports.AddRange(GetReportsFinal(GetDirectReportsList(result)));
                    directReports.AddRange(GetDirectReportsList(result));
                    directReports.Add(result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString() + " (" + result.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString()+")");
                }
                else
                {
                    directReports.Add(result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString() + " (" + result.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString() + ")");
                }

            }


            foreach(var item in directReports)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }
            return directReports;
        }
```

```
        public bool hasDirectReports(SearchResult result)
        {
            if(result.Properties["directreports"].Count >= 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```
        public List<string> GetDirectReportsList(SearchResult result)
        {
            List<string> formattedDirectReportsList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var thing in result.Properties["directreports"])
            {
                string employeeString = thing.ToString();
                //employeeString = employeeString.Split(setp, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                employeeString = employeeString.Replace("CN=", "");
                employeeString = employeeString.TrimEnd(',');
                employeeString = employeeString.Replace("\\, ", ", ");
                //Debug.WriteLine(employeeString);
                if (employeeString.Split(',')[2] == "OU=Users")
                {
                    string fn = employeeString.Split(',')[1];
                    string ln = employeeString.Split(',')[0];
                    var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "somedomain");
                    UserPrincipal directreportname = new UserPrincipal(domain);
                    directreportname.Name = ln + "," + fn;
                    PrincipalSearcher prinsearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
                    prinsearcher.QueryFilter = directreportname;
                    DirectorySearcher dirsearcher = prinsearcher.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;
                    Principal reportResults = prinsearcher.FindOne();
                    formattedDirectReportsList.Add(reportResults.DisplayName + " (" + reportResults.SamAccountName + ")");
                    DirectReports(reportResults.DisplayName);
                }
            }
            return formattedDirectReportsList;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what the issue is. Is this code working properly?

Comment: No it doesn’t if you call the directreports method and pass it the Displayname of the director it only returns the directors direct reports not his/her reports and the reports of his/her managers. I think that when I call the directreports method recursively it creates a new list ultimately clearing the first list and I’m not sure how to keep the values with each iteration

Comment: OK, so why not just call `DirectReports` once for each person you need? Or are you looking to get the entire hierarchy all at once?

Comment: I’m not following you, the idea was to provide a name and return any and all employees under that person in list form if there are any.That list would then be used to populate a select list.

Comment: I'm also not following you either. Your first comment implies that you want the entire tree of company employees, starting from the director, then his/her reports, then their reports, and so on, until you get to the people who have nobody reporting to them. But your second comment makes it sound you want to give one name and then get only their direct reports, and that's it.